# Variable works for first if statement but returns undefined in else if

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

dropdownSelection works for the first if statement fine. However when it moves on to the else it throws an undefined. What would cause that?

```
let dropdownSelection = defaultDropDown.options[defaultDropDown.selectedIndex].value

if(dropdownSelection === "Sales"){
        for (let i = 0; i < systemsData.length; i++){
            if(systemsData[i].parentID === 1){
                let sales = systemsData[i].sysName
                let option = document.createElement('option')
                option.textContent = sales
                subSystemDropDown.appendChild(option)
                console.log('Sales Online')
            } 
        }
    } else if(dropdownSelection === "Operations"){
        for (let i = 0; i < systemsData.length; i++){
            if(systemsData[i].parentID === 2){
                let operations = systemsData[i].sysName
                let option = document.createElement('option')
                option.textContent = operations
                subSystemDropDown.appendChild(option)
                console.log('Operations Online')
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide the "defaultDropDown.selectedIndex" and "defaultDropDown.options" in the description please first.

Comment: The answer you have posted is more relevant to a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer